# Need to get application's users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to get all users who authorize an application.
And same things for users who remove an application's authorizations.

I have check in Graph API and FQL and don't found that.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save user details in your own database to have a list of installed users.  In order to track users who unauthorized your app you'll have to implement a `Deauthorize Callback`.  The settings for that callback can be found in the advanced tab of your application settings.  You can find more information on this at this url : 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/
Scroll down to "App Deauthorization".

Comment: Great, thanks

And no way to get, at a T instant, a list of app's users? :(

Comment: and if the user remove only "email" persmission for example. What is happening?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure - I think you might have to check what permissions the user has ganted when they arrive at your application and cross reference your list of requested permissions.  If there is a difference then you will know that the user removed some permission. You should set it up and run some tests - it is possible that the Deauthorize Callback will still be called...